# When i rotate the image with mousemove i can't get negative X degree

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to 3d move a picture. When I'm past half the picture the mouse offsetX should be positive but else should be increase a negative way. How can i do that for rotate degree?

My experiment like that:

```js
$('#img').mousemove(function (event) {
    $(this).removeClass('transition-effect');
    let mouseX = event.offsetX;
    let itemWidth = $(this).width();
    let degree = (10 * mouseX) / itemWidth;// For maximize to 10 degree
    let negativeDegree = -((10 * mouseX) / itemWidth);// For get a negative degree
    if (mouseX >= itemWidth/2) {
       // console.log(`itemWidth:${itemWidth/2} - mouseX:${mouseX}`);
        $(this).css('transform', 'perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + degree + 'deg)');
        $(this).css('box-shadow', '' + degree + 'px 0px 20px #fbe989');
    }else{
        $(this).css('transform', 'perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + negativeDegree+ 'deg)');
        $(this).css('box-shadow', '' + negativeDegree + 'px 0px 20px #fbe989');
    }

}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).addClass('transition-effect');
    $(this).css('box-shadow', '1px 0px 20px #c1c1c1');
    $(this).css('transform', 'perspective(0) rotateY(0deg)');
})
```

```css
.transition-effect{
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.cumhuriyet.com.tr/Archive/2021/8/3/1857648/kapak_173121.jpg"
  class="img-fluid img-thumbnail take-it" id="img">
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code and the image etc?

Comment: i post it @ComputersEnthusiast

Comment: Sure sorry for bad english i hope u understand it @ComputersEnthusiast

Comment: This is look like solve my problem thank you for your help. But look like i can't mark it before 15 points. I will come here after for your mark :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that you had mouseX = 0 on the left, so at that point you should compute mouseX - the distance (so, mouseX - image width / 2, i.e. -200 for example), then convert it to positive for the angle and add a - to the degree.

```js
$('#img').mousemove(function (event) {
    $(this).removeClass('transition-effect');
    let mouseX = event.offsetX;
    let itemWidth = $(this).width();
    let half = itemWidth / 2;
    let degree = mouseX >= half ? ((10 * mouseX) / itemWidth) : (((-(mouseX - itemWidth)) * 10)/itemWidth);        
    let negativeDegree = -((10 * mouseX) / itemWidth);// For get a negative degree
    if (mouseX >= half) {
       // console.log(`itemWidth:${itemWidth/2} - mouseX:${mouseX}`);
        $(this).css('transform', 'perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + degree + 'deg)');
        $(this).css('box-shadow', '' + degree + 'px 0px 20px #fbe989');
    }else{
        $(this).css('transform', 'perspective(1000px) rotateY(-' + degree+ 'deg)');
        $(this).css('box-shadow', '-' + degree + 'px 0px 20px #fbe989');
    }

}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).addClass('transition-effect');
    $(this).css('box-shadow', '1px 0px 20px #c1c1c1');
    $(this).css('transform', 'perspective(0) rotateY(0deg)');
})
```

```css
.transition-effect{
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.cumhuriyet.com.tr/Archive/2021/8/3/1857648/kapak_173121.jpg"
  class="img-fluid img-thumbnail take-it" id="img">
```

Comment: Now I need to start the degree from 0 for the two halves. I will try this for smooth transition.

Comment: Yeah, that's a minor detail, let me know if it doesn't work. But basically you can remove the check if mouseX > half and just put the degrees.

Answer (score 0):

My last code like that for smooth transition:

```js
$('#img').mousemove(function (event) {
    $(this).removeClass('transition-effect');

    let itemWidth = $(this).width();
    let mousesX = event.offsetX;
    let half = itemWidth / 2;
    let mouseX = mousesX >= half ? Math.abs((itemWidth - mousesX) - half)  : -((itemWidth - mousesX) - half);
//console.log(mouseX);
    let degree = ((10 * mouseX) / itemWidth) ;
    let negativeDegree = -((10 * mouseX) / itemWidth);// For get a negative degree
    //console.log((itemWidth - mouseX) - half);
    if (mouseX >= half) {
        // console.log(`itemWidth:${itemWidth/2} - mouseX:${mouseX}`);
        $(this).css('transform', 'perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + degree + 'deg)');
        $(this).css('box-shadow', '-' + degree + 'px 0px 10px gray');
    } else {
        $(this).css('transform', 'perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + degree + 'deg)');
        $(this).css('box-shadow', '' + degree + 'px 0px 10px gray');
    }

}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).addClass('transition-effect');
    $(this).css('box-shadow', '1px 0px 20px #c1c1c1');
    $(this).css('transform', 'perspective(0) rotateY(0deg)');
})
```

```css
 .transition-effect{
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <img src="https://www.cumhuriyet.com.tr/Archive/2021/8/3/1857648/kapak_173121.jpg"
  class="img-fluid img-thumbnail take-it" id="img">
```